# Is it possible to make Visual Studio change the project's Platform Toolset automatically?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am developing a project using Visual Studio with my friend. I have **Visual Studio 2015**, while he has **VS 2013**. I'm facing an annoying problem that whenever I do a git pull and receives changes my friend made from the remote repository, Visual Studio changes the platform toolset to **v120** (his platform toolset) and I can't build the solution. To fix the problem, I always have to change the Platform Toolset manually back to my version (**v140**). The same also happens with him when I push to the repository and he pulls.

We are wondering if there is a way to make the Visual Studio indentify the correct Platform Toolset and change it automatically when building the project.

We tried to use macros such as:

```
($PlatformToolset)
($PlatformToolsetVersion)
v($PlatformToolsetVersion)
vc($PlatformToolsetVersion)
```

But nothing seems to be working. The project only compiles if we don't use macros and set manually the Platform Toolset.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're both modifying and committing the same file, even though you each need that file to be something different, because the file is version-specific and you are using different versions.

What happens is this - you set the toolset to v140. This causes your project file to change. Git sees the file as changed and commits the new version. Your friend pulls and gets the new version. Annoyed, he sets the toolset to v12. Git sees the file as changed and.. the cycle repeats.

What you should be doing, is only collaborating on files that you have in common e.g. source files. You don't have the project file in common, because you each need one that works for a different version of Visual Studio. So maintain two versions - one for VS2013 and one for VS2015. When you need to modify the build process itself, you will need to make changes to both. But that's probably a good idea anyway, because you can't be sure that some feature of VS2015 you're using in your project [is even available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx) in VS2013.

If you've ever compiled an open source project where the author provided solution files for Visual Studio, you'll notice that they will provide separate solution files for each version they support. Your project needs to support two versions, so you need two sets of solution/project files.

If you want to avoid that, the other solution is to switch to a cross-platform build process that abstracts away the build tools e.g. [SCons](http://www.scons.org/). Then you can either have the build process auto-generate Visual Studio build files for you, or you can configure a Makefile project in Visual Studio that you never have to change again, which calls the external build process. In your case that might be a little more complex than you require, but is probably a better longer term solution for bigger projects that need to support multiple platforms.